# How to match value with Date/Time picker month(short Format) in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access, datetimepicker

I have an MS Access database which contains a `table1` and that table has a column **Date/time picker** (Format is short). I want to enter month in text Box and match with  Date/time picker, and retrieve all month with match this textBox value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
select * from myTable where DATEPART("m", yourDateField) = @InputtedMonth;
```

Replace *@InputtedMonth* with a your Textbox's value.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "select s_Id,rec_No,fee_Date,total_Fee from Fee where DATEPART('m',Fee.fee_Date as fee_Date) =#"+textMonth          This query give Error

Comment: @mr.prince first of all, try to execute the query in your access. Try to debug your code also, using breakpoints and find the error

Comment: @mr.prince I'm not surprised. I gave you correct query, but it change it to incorrect query. Use next: *select s_Id,rec_No,fee_Date,total_Fee from Fee where DATEPART("m", fee_Date) = 10* it will give you all records from October

Comment: Dear in this "m" give error.because query is alreay in double quate.How to solve this .  Double quate with in double quate not exceptable